# EditText getText().toString() is not showing the full text Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText and I call `EditText.getText().toString()` when a button is clicked but when I print out the String, a few characters are missing

My code:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String result = editText.getText().toString();
                Log.d(TAG, result);
            }
        });
```

XML:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:background="@drawable/border_edit_text"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:maxHeight="570dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/speakTextBtn"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.016" />
```

Here are some images of it:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6MUM.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5CDl.png]

Comment: Remove bias both of them.

Comment: What's debug mode saying?

Comment: Same. Words with a few letters missing

Answer (score 0):

```
    android:autoLink="all"
    android:ems="10"
```

Can you please remove those above-mentioned properties and give a try.

Comment: It is still replacing a few characters with space